# Change array elements with a stream without converting its collection

Tags: java

How to make this the modern java way with lambda or a stream?

```
void foo (String[] ary)
{
  for (int i=0;i<ary.length;i++)
  {
    ary[i] += "_abc";
  }
  
  bar (ary);  // whatever
}
```

I can do it with map and then collect it to a List and then to an array but - but it seems a bit overkill compared to the "old" code.

```
ary = (String[]) Arrays.stream (ary).map (a -> a+"_abc").collect (Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

Is there no way without the converting stuff (array -> stream, list -> array)?

Comment: There is no modern way, arrays are fixed memory sized and when using them, it is always a decision for preformance and memory size. Turning an array to a list just to benefit from the stream API and then turning it back to an array is just overkill. Don't do it.

Comment: "but it seems a bit overkill compared to the "old" code" Correct, so keep using the old code then.

Comment: "*How to make this the modern java way*" -> don't, why you want that? It is an overkill: not better to read, creating a couple of `Stream`, `List`, array instances. Sure, you could use `IntStream.range(...).forEach(i -> arr[i] += ...`) but that is even worse IMHO (for this use case)

Comment: And just to bear in mind: calling the stram API is slow, so as long as there is no specific reason for that (eg. tens of thousands of items to be processed) classic loops are always much more performant.

Comment: If you want to improve readability, you could use enhanced for instead of indexes for looping

Comment: You can change `bar` to take a `List` and save the final conversion back to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
void foo (String[] ary)
{
    String[] args = Stream.of(ary)
            .map(a -> a + "_abc")
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    bar (args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mutate the initial array with streams, but it's better not to. Generally stream operations should **not** cause side effects.

```
void foo(String[] ary) {
  IntStream.range(0, ary.length)
        .forEach(i -> ary[i] += "_abc");
  bar(ary);
}
```

Better stick with the loop approach, this is simulating a loop to get the indexes, so you are just getting an overhead for no real benefit.

If you are fine getting a new array, not mutating the initial, then streams can cleanly do the job:

```
void foo(String[] ary) {
  String[] res = Stream.of(ary)
           .map(string -> string + "_abc")
           .toArray(String[]::new);
  bar(res);
}
```